# WP REST API sorting comments

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest

I am trying to sort comments - I want to see reply to comment to be under original comment (fe. reply to comment 1 is under comment 1).
I have tried

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=${id}&order=asc&orderby=parent
```

and it works most of the times but some comments are in the wrong place (fe. reply to comment 3 is under comment 1).
What is the correct way to sort comments?